# Problems with APA bibliography in Wiley style njd-v2.cls

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm somehow getting crazy with a "small" thing. I used the `njd-v2.cls` style (for submission) wit AMA citing. So I had

```
\documentclass[AMA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
```

and changed it to

```
\documentclass[APA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}

...

\bibliography{my_bib}
```

because I want to use the APA citation style now. my_bib is a *.bib file. Further I downloaded all style files etc. Now I get a reference list but some errors as well:

> Undefined control sequence. \begin{thebibliography}{}
>
> fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015(fixltx2e) All fixes
> are now in the LaTeX kernel.
>
> You have requested package `NJDapacite', but the package provides` apacite'. Unused global option(s): [APA,STIX1COL].

So something is going wrong and I tried hours to fix it but I don't understand what's going on. And I don't find any examples using this style file with APA.

Can anybody help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the `APA` option in this new Wiley style is looking for the following files:

1. [NJDapacite.sty](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabbiocrux/Climatelabs-paper/main/NJDapacite.sty)
2. [WileyNJD-APA.bst](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-demonstration-of-the-latex-class-file-for-wiley-njd-journals/bfwqvgnbgcjc) (under the Additional Template file)

After which, you can just add the following option in your `documentclass` as follows:

```
\documentclass[APA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
```

Hope it helps!